# Java default JRE parameters on Unix

Tags: unix, java

Is it possible to configure java in unix to always add a JRE parameter whenever java is run?
e.g. `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=25800`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a wrapper script and add it to your path. Something like this

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                               

java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=25800 "$@"
```

Call it java-local.sh or some other fancy name and just use it in place of the `java` binary. Of course this one is pretty basic but I am sure it caters for like 90% of the cases. As a shell exercise, you could make it an alias for your user (but then it only works for your user):

```
# alias java='java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=25800'
```

Comment: +1 Recommend double-quoting `$@` to preserve arguments in the face of whitespace.  (Sorry, I'd have edited that in myself, but I have repeatedly, comically, and miserably failed the CAPTCHA.)

Answer (score 3):

You could create an alias

```
alias java='java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=25800'
```

You could also play around with [Application Resource Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/beyond/env/source.html) which may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

[IBM java](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/rzaha/sdpropf.htm) has support for a `SystemDefault.properties` file, where each line specifies one Java system property or command line option. but I  can't see anything similar for the oracle JDK, and there is a similar thread gone unanswered here;
https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2131751

stracing openjdk during startup, seems to indicate that it does not look for any ".properties" files, so I am guessing that the answer is no. But there might be a Java expert come along with a better answer.